# Error running Basic Spring Batch example - Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver

Tags: java, maven, spring-batch

I am trying to run the example Spring batch project using the simple spring batch project template in STS (SpringSource Tool Suite).

To do this I ran the following steps in Eclipse:

Right click -> New -> Other
 Selected SpringSource Tool Suite -> Spring Template Project -> Simple Spring Batch
 Entered a relevant Project name and Package name

I then try to run the project using

```
mvn exec:java
```

I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'exampleConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository com.spring.hello.ExampleConfiguration.jobRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not get Connection for extracting meta data; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver'
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1074)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner.start(CommandLineJobRunner.java:282)
at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner.main(CommandLineJobRunner.java:574)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:290)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository com.spring.hello.ExampleConfiguration.jobRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not get Connection for extracting meta data; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver'
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
... 20 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not get Connection for extracting meta data; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver'
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:848)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:790)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:707)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
... 22 more
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not get Connection for extracting meta data; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver'
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:293)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:320)
at org.springframework.batch.support.DatabaseType.fromMetaData(DatabaseType.java:93)
at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JobRepositoryFactoryBean.java:145)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
... 32 more
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver'
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:280)
... 37 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver'
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1136)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:880)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:319)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1130)
... 41 more
```

It looks like the HSQLDB driver is not being found and/or loaded correctly.

I have checked the Maven dependencies and the hsqldb is definitely in there and being pulled in to Eclipse on the classpath.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

Any ideas why I would see this?

EDIT: Added ApplicationContext xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:batch.properties" />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.hello" />

<jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource">
    <jdbc:script location="${batch.schema.script}" />
</jdbc:initialize-database>

<batch:job-repository id="jobRepository" />

<import resource="classpath:/META-INF/spring/module-context.xml" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sometimes,Eclipse behaves strange. i guess eclipse is not able to update the project build path with your newly added dependencies(HSQLDB driver) . I advice you to use maven integration plugin for eclipse http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/ which will make your life easy.you can download it from eclipse(juno) marketplace.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am actually already using this plugin and can see the dependency on the project class path in Eclipse. So I assume that means Eclipse can find it

Comment: ok. try this then , right click on project,Maven-->Update Project.and I hope you have the jdbc driver(hsqldb-1.8.*.jar) in the M2 repository.This should work.

Comment: I tried this but unfortunately no change. I really think Eclipse can find the JAR as it is listed under the Maven dependencies folder on the project build path.

Comment: ok. could  you please paste your applicationContext.xml for reference. bydaway and i am also suspecting there might be mismatch between the hsqldb version and the jdbc connector jar version.

Comment: I have added it to the question. Note this is the standard one from the STS sample project. I am going to try cleaning all the jars in my local mvn repository and rebuilding.

Comment: Clearing my entire local repository and then rebuilding has fixed the problem. I guess there was some corrupt JAR in there or something.

Comment: Thanks for the help, ill accept the answer as there are multiple solutions in this answer and comment discussion